# How to change color of mouse-over tile identifier in UI?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

When you mouse-over (or otherwise place the cursor over) tiles, the UI identifies them in an extremely dark blue-on-black that is impossible for me to read. For example, to identify *trunk pillar* or *dark grass*.

Is there any way to change this? Nearly any other color would be preferred.

I found a page on customizing the color scheme, but I don't think it changes elements outside of the map. ( https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Color_scheme )

[image: Dark blue identifier text is unreadable.]

Any  help would be much appreciated.

Okay, exiting colors.txt actually did work. I didn't realize it applied to the entire UI. This tool helped me out a lot:

https://manmademagic.github.io/DFColorGen/

Comment: Actually colors.txt changes elements *everywhere*. Did you try changing it?

Comment: ...could you add your edit as an answer instead?